# jQuery animation timing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have here a function and what I want to happen is to display the div first before it smoothly changes it's width.. Unfortunately what happen is that the width already changes once it appears

CSS:

```
#frame12{
    opacity:0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);
    width:100;
}
```

jQuery:

```
function animatestamp(){
    jQuery("div#frame12").css({'opacity':'1','filter':'alpha(opacity=100)'}).animate({
    width:'451px'
},animatestamp);
}
```

Comment: Please change the title to something meaningful

Comment: may be you need jquery delay()?

Comment: Are you caling it recursively, or am I missing something?

Comment: @zaw.. can you show me how? I'm new to jquery

Comment: @Skarlinski yes i want to call it recursively

Comment: In the css, add px to width

Comment: It looks wrong, but maybe there is a reason you're doing it. Why are you setting the speed of the animation, using the name of the function?

Comment: Did you mean something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/WUzHS/

Comment: He is calling the function as a callback, recursively. Although I really can't guess why one would want to do that

Comment: Now that I think about it, aren't you locked in infinite recursion?

Comment: @PSL yess.. you got my point.. that's what I want to achive :)

Comment: @g3rriascn You want an answer..? :)

Comment: @PSL yess. can you give me the answer? :0 .. and one thing more. how to loop it?

Comment: You want to loop what?

Comment: I want to call the function recursively to repeat the animation you showed me..

Comment: You want to it to become visible and wide and then shrink and invisible?

Comment: yap. I want it to be visible then shrink then abruptly go to its default size than fade out.. I'm having this to achive a stamp like animation.

Comment: @g3rriascn like this? http://jsfiddle.net/zGj7a/

Comment: @PSL.. yes dude ur great.. you save my day.. one more thing if it's ok.. when going back to it's normal size. How to make ti without animating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use animate on div's opacity first and then on its complete callback animate the width.

```
function animatestamp() {
    jQuery("#frame12").animate({ //animate the opacity first
        'opacity': 1,
        'filter': 'alpha(opacity=100)'
    }, 2000, function () { //Once it is completely visible start animating the width
        $(this).animate({
            'width': '451px',
        }, 1000);
    });
}
animatestamp();
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WUzHS/)**

For recursive you can try this:

```
var $frame = jQuery("#frame12");

function getWidthConfig(elem) { //get the width animate object based on current elem width
    return {
        'width': elem.width() > 450 ? '100px': '451px' 
    }
}

function getOpacityConfig(elem) {//get the opacity animate object based on current elem opacity
    var opac = +elem.css('opacity');

    return {
        'opacity': !opac ? 1 : 0,
        'filter': !opac ? 'alpha(opacity=100)' : 'alpha(opacity=0)'
    }
}

function animatestamp() {
    $frame.animate(getOpacityConfig($frame), 2000, function () {
        $frame.animate(getWidthConfig($frame), 1000, animatestampReverse);
    });
}

function animatestampReverse() {
    $frame.delay(2000).animate(getWidthConfig($frame), 1000, function () {
        $frame.animate(getOpacityConfig($frame), 2000, animatestamp)
    });

}
animatestamp();
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UTXcY/)**

Answer (score 1):

Animate opacity & filter first, then animate the width as PSL well said but also in your CSS, change "width:100;" to "width:100px;" (Add measurement unit "px") or otherwise the div's initial width would be screen width  (add a border to your css to see the difference visually) and to make your js simpler and more readable, use chaining in your Javascript:

CSS:

```
#frame12{    
   opacity:0;
   filter:alpha(opacity=0);
   width:100px;  /*Add px to avoid max screen witdth and CSS Flash */
   border: solid 1px; /* to see the real div width */
 }
```

Javascript:

```
function animatestamp() {
    $("div#frame12")
        .animate({ 'opacity': 1, 'filter': 'alpha(opacity=100)' }, 2000)
        .animate({ width: '451px'}, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Need more code to be sure, but I'm guessing its because you have not set an explicit width on that container before applying an animation to the width property. Could try this:

```
function animatestamp(){
  $("#frame12").css({
    'opacity':'1',
    'filter':'alpha(opacity=100)',
    'width': $(this).width()
  }).animate({
    width:'451px'
  }, animatestamp);
}
```

Or just set it in the css...

```
#frame12 { width: 100px; }
```

... and remove the 'width' from the css() above.